# Prove a graph is $2$-connected if a path from $x$ to $y$ can avoid any vertex $z$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be graph with $|V| \geq 3$ such that for any three vertices $x, y$ and $z$ there is path from $x$ to $y$ in $G$ that doesn't contain vertex $z$. How can I prove that $G$ is $2$-connected in terms of vertices?

Comment: Suppose that you remove vertex $x$. Let $y$ and $z$ be two vertices in the remaining graph, $G-x$. Is there a path from $y$ to $z$ in $G-x$?

Comment: I think there can be. Because I can look at them like those two vertices $x$ and $y$

Comment: Yes, with $x$ playing the part of $z$ in the condition. And that shows that $G$ is $2$-connected.

Comment: That easy? Shouldn't I first proof that ``there is path from $x$ to $y$ in G that doesn't contain $z$` is still true in graph G-x?

Comment: Also, removing just $x$ doesn't make my graph unconnected right?

Comment: Any path from $y$ to $z$ in $G$ that doesn't contain $x$ is also a path in $G-x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your graph $G$ cannot be disconnected, otherwise you could take any vertices $x$ and $y$ in separate components and there would be no path connecting them regardless of your choice of $z$.

But your graph also cannot have a single cut vertex. Otherwise if it had one cut vertex $z$, you could take vertices $x$ and $y$ in separate components of $G-z$ and there would have to be a path between $x$ and $y$ that didn't pass through $z$. But this path would also have to exist in $G-z$, so removing $z$ did not disconnect $G$.

So you graph must be $2$-connected.